Linux OS does not see all the RAM allocated to the VM by Proxmox
I recently added a new VM in ProxMox for various web services. I originally allocated a minimum of 8GB of RAM with ballooning available to 16 GB. All seemed to be well until I tried installing Collabora, when the VM basically locked up for several hours.

Looking at ProxMox, it was using 104% of the allocated processor time for that whole time, but only 5% of the allocated RAM.
When I ran the free --mega command on the VM, it told me that there is only 938 MB total RAM in the system.
$ free --mega
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             938         715          99          71         350         223
Swap:           1022         672         349



I have way more than enough RAM in the bare metal server (120 GB) to allocate 8/16 GB of RAM to this VM, but the Debian OS installed in the VM only sees 938 MB.  This is not a problem with any of the other VMs I have, including the other Debian VM I spun up the same day.  I have tried disabling the ballooning, and even reducing the RAM to 4 GB to see if it will shake something loose, but I never get a different amount of RAM from free, and the memory usage graph never, ever goes above the 900 MB area:

Everything I find when I search for issues are about VMs trying to use too much RAM or maxing out the RAM.  I can't find anything about the guest OS not seeing 95% of the RAM.  Does anyone have any ideas?

What exactly is a system you run in a VM? Does it support PAE (physical address extension) which is necessary for a 32-bit OS to leverage RAM beyond 1G?

There might be clues in the output of journalctl -b on the VM. info balloon in the VM "monitor" tab in PVE to see current balloon status.

What's the full  command line for the kvm process running the VM emulation? Is it different from the other working VMs? What about kernel version and parameters in the VMs?

@StéphaneChazelas
I turned the memory back up to minimum 8G with max 16G
This is the result of the info balloon:
balloon: actual=16384 max_mem=16384 total_mem=894 free_mem=71 mem_swapped_in=659345408 mem_swapped_out=1546711040 major_page_faults=154299 minor_page_faults=1738481 last_update=1726289416

@StéphaneChazelas - I compared two configs that were created the same day, this one with 8/16G and the other with 4/8G.  They look practically the same except for the memory numbers.  I ran stress -m 1 --vm-bytes 4G on the second one and it easily used up the RAM.  When I ran it on the first one, it would not run because it could not allocate the RAM.

Since the only VMs that are having issues are the debian VMs (all of them having issues now, even the ones that have been running fine for months), I tried rolling back the kernel on one of the debian VMs to  6.1.0-23-amd64 and  6.1.0-21-amd64, but the behavior persists.  I suspect that the issue may have started when I installed the newest version of debian on the new VMs and then updated the other VMs.  Is it possible that debian had a bug in one of the packages?  Is there a specific package that would manage the RAM it detects from the hypervisor?

It turns out that the issue was memory hotplug being enabled on the VMs, since it is not enabled by default on Debian for some reason. Once I disabled memory hotplug, the VMs started working correctly again.
